# PySerial read() returning incorrect values

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I have an Arduino with a standard analog temp sensor powered up by the USB port of a Raspberry Pi, and a Python script that gets all incoming values.

However, I find that the incoming values are off by about 10deg.

When I hook it up to my computer, the serial monitor returns the correct value. That narrows it down to an error on the Raspberry Pi I think.

Python code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
    temp = float(ser.readline())
    tempstring = "{:.1f}".format(temp)
    print(tempstring)
    f = open("/var/www/temp", "w")
    f.write(tempstring)
    f.close()
```

Arduino code (for good measure)

```
const int thermometer = A0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  int sensorReading = analogRead(thermometer);
  float volts = (sensorReading/1024.0) * 5.0;
  float temp = (volts - 0.5) * 100.0;
  int largeTemp = temp * 100.0;


  Serial.println(largeTemp);
  delay(10000);
}
```

I didn't want to bother with sending a float, hence the  `int largeTemp = temp * 100.0;` line.

Comment: My bet is the Pi's USB port is supplying too low a voltage, throwing the readings off.

Comment: That is indeed a possibility. But wouldn't that make the readings go down, not up? EDIT: Also, how would I use another powersupply? I'm using the USB for data transfer.

Comment: I second DavidSchwartz, stronger powersupply may improve the situation.

Comment: @user3433131 A lower voltage would make the readings go up. Do the math. Your code multiplies by 5.0. It should be multiplying by, say, 4.5. So you get a value that's too high. Do this: 1) Measure the supply voltage with a voltmeter. 2) Back figure the value of `sensorReading`. 3) Re-compute the temp replacing `5.0` with the measured voltage. If that fixes it, my theory is proven.

Comment: By the way, 4.5V to 4.75V is typical for the Pi's USB ports. Try a powered hub (though some of those are over 5V by as much as .6 volts). If you care about accuracy, the supply voltage should be measured, not hardcoded. (Or the device calibrated in its final form. Or regulate the supply voltage. Or some other solution.)